# Can't Find Any Backups After Uninstalling And Installing Whatsapp Because It Told Me To Do So

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, cloud

I was a Whatsapp beta user. A few hours ago it wanted me to update the app because my version is no longer viable. I tried doing that, then it told me, since I was a Beta user I need to first delete Whatsapp, opt out of Beta, then download it again. I wanted to make a manual back up since last one was from 2 AM but it didn't let me enter the app, just that announcement page. Then I said "Okay, I already have back-up. I will lose messages for only one day. Okie dokie." Then,

1. I uninstalled whatsapp
2. Opted out of beta
3. Installed it back, didn't prompt me for local back-up
4. I tried to find cloud back-ups, turns out I don't have any (weird).
5. I tried to find back-ups manually using a file manager: there is none (weirder).
   6.?

My phone made back-ups every day at 2 AM. I have seen it for years. Where are they? Messages themselves aren't that important but the images are gone too! Only thing that is in my Whatsapp folder is a "media" file that has images, videos, and audios which are passed down from my old phone.

It remembers my profile picture and header photos of the groups.